# check whether an array is multidimensional

Tags: c#, arrays, interface, icollection

as I am implementing the ICollection-Interface in my class I want to implement the CopyTo-Method and I have to throw an Argument-exception if the array is multidimensional. 
What is meant by this? The head of my method is this

public void CopyTo(MyClass[] array, int arrayIndex)

I thought these brackets would mean that the given array is one-dimensional but when I automatically import the comments from the Interface the comment appears, that I have to check for multidimensionality. 
Can someone explain it to me?

With kind regards

Sebastia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at Array.Rank? However, T[] is one dimensional. You mainly need to check the rank when all you know is "Array". This is because the actual method is exposed via Array, not T[].

So in short - don't worry about it in this scenario ;-p

Comment: The interface signature for ICollection<T> is actually CopyTo(T[]array,int arrayIndex) and the ICollection comments tells you to check for multidimension arrays so this must mean that T[] is not a constraint for single dimension arrays. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, you "cannot convert from 'int[*,*]' to 'int[]'.  Try:

`int[,] test = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };`
`ICollection<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };`
`list.CopyTo(test, 0);`